# How to "type" random package return

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I'm building an API to allow for plugins in an application I'm working on. I'm using `importlib.import_module` to import the plugins. Clearly I have no idea what modules are going to be imported ahead of time. Is there a way to identify the return type as a generic module on the method I'm using to do the imports?

```
def import_plugin(plugin_name: str) -> <Some generic module type>:
    # conditional tests here...
    return importlib.import_module("plugins.{}".format(plugin_name))
```

Comment: You mean `types.ModuleType`?

Comment: Modules don't have a "return type" — so it's unclear what you mean.

Comment: @martineau presumably, the return type for this function, which will dynamically import modules.

Comment: @khelwood that's exactly the type of thing I was looking for. This will work. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: It did I'm surprised it didn't come up easier when I was searching. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a module is given by `types.ModuleType` in the `types` module.

```py
import types
type(types) is types.ModuleType
# => True
```

Answer (score 0):

Python uses [duck typing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/duck-typing-in-python/), so I recommend assuming it is a module, and if it is not let the user handle it. If you really want to get the type, use `types.ModuleType` as khelwood said.